# jQuery force mouse move and click

Tags: jquery, click, mousemove

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thisizmonster/VRPDa/

Purpose:

1. Mouse must move to button position (button position must auto calculate)
2. Fire mouse click event

How do it?

**Edited/Added**

Since everyone said I can't move mouse coordinate, I think its failed. Btw my main purpose is because of Facebook Comment plugin. By default its shows "by social ranking". My requirement is default by "Reverse Chronological". But plugin itself placed in iFrame, So I can't access its elements. So I decided after page loaded, quickly move mouse and choose option and revert back mouse coordinate. Its failed I think :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Not possible
2. `$('#item').click();` or `$('#item').trigger('click');` (use the latter for other triggers like `mouseenter`

Answer (score 10):

Fortunately, you cannot control the mouse-pointer position through Javascript.

Comment: Why is this fortunate?

Comment: @fibono: Imagine if it were actually possible. Malicious scripts could intentionally move the cursor over the banners, links, various other elements, and then simulate clicking on them, flooding the user with unwanted content.